# Call route from button click laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, balde

I am using the Laravel framework and the blade templating engine for one of my projects, where I have a route which looks like

```
Route::get('/problems/{problem-id}/edit', 'AdminController@editProblem');
```

I have **editProblem** method in **AdminController** which returns a view

```
public function editProblem(Problem $problem) {
        return view('admin.problem-edit', compact('problem'));
    }
```

and I have a button on a view which looks like

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Edit</button>
```

Now I want to call this route with the `$problem->id` when the button will be clicked. I need to pass these value on the route.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### In my opnion, you should use url() Laravel method

To call you route with the problem's id you can do:

```
<a href="{{ url('/problems/' . $problem->id . '/edit') }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Edit</a>
```

I used an anchor tag, but it will be rendered like you button tag because I kept the same style class you have defined.

#### Why you should use url() method ?

The reason is simple, the url method will get the full url to your controller. If you don't use this, href link will get appended with current url.

For example, supose you button is located inside a given page

> yourdomain.com/a-given-page/

when someone click in your button, the result will be:

> yourdomain.com/a-given-page/problems/{problem-id}/edit

when you would like to get this:

> yourdomain.com/problems/{problem-id}/edit

#### Some considerations about your editProblem method

Your route has the '$id', so you need to receive this '$id' in your method

```
public function editProblem($problem_id) {

$problem = \App\Problem::find($problem_id); //If you have your model 'Problem' located in your App folder

return view('admin.problem-edit', compact('problem'));
}
```

Comment: Hi @HL96, this '{{' doesn't work inside other '{{'.  So I removed the inner curly brackets and I left this as follows:   `href="{{ url('/problems/' . $problem->id . '/edit') }}"`

Answer (score 9):

Try This:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url("users/index") }}'">Button</button>
```

**Little Suggestion:**
When you're defining routes in laravel give it a unique name, it helps you to keep track on each url like this

```
Route::get('/problems/{problem-id}/edit', 'AdminController@editProblem')->name('showProblemEditPage');
Route::post('/problems/{problem-id}/edit', 'AdminController@updateProblem')->name('updateProblem');
```

Now you use this route in blade with just name for post and get both

> **Exmaple of GET route :**

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ route("showProblemEditPage",[$problemIdParameter]) }}'">Button</button>
```

**OR**

```
<a href="{{ route("showProblemEditPage",[$problemIdParameter]) }}">Button</button>
```

**OR**

```
<button type="button redirectToUrl" data-redirect-url="{{ route("showProblemEditPage",[$problemIdParameter]) }}">Button</button>
<script>
  $(document).on('click','.redirectToUrl',function(){
    let getRedirectUrl = $(this).attr('data-redirect-url');
    window.location.href= getRedirectUrl;
  });
</script>
```

> Example of POST route :

In case if you are submiting form via submit button click

```
<form action={{ route('updateProblem',[$problemIdParameter]) }}>
  .....

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In case if you are submiting form via ajax on button click

```
<form action={{ route('updateProblem',[$problemIdParameter]) }}>
  .....

  <button type="button" class="submitForm" >Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
   $(document).on('click','.submitForm',function(){
      let getForm = $(this).parents('form');
      let getFormActionUrl = getForm.attr('action');
      $.ajax({
          url: getFormActionUrl,
          .....
          .....
          .....
          .....
          .....
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You will need to create a link to this route:

```
<a href="/problems/{{ $problem->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Edit</a>
```

If you use named routes, this will be even easier:

```
Route::get('/problems/{problem-id}/edit', ['as' => 'problems.edit', 'uses' => 'AdminController@editProblem']);
```

And then you just need to call the `route` method:

```
<a href="{{ route('problems.edit', $problem->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Edit</a>
```

Comment: if I want to use `<button>` instead of `<a>` then how can I do it ?

Comment: Then you will need to add some javascript. Like: `<button data-href="...">` and then catch the click with JS and redirect.

Comment: @mostafiz13 You should semantically use an anchor in this case. Although there is no hard and fast rule, it makes little sense to use a button to navigate a user, as thats exactly what a anchor is for.

Answer (score 1):

Was asked for route inquiry.
so that :

```
<button  onclick="window.location='{{ route("some_route_name") }}'"...>
</button>
```

in *web.php*

```
Route::get('/some_route_url', [SomeRouteController::class,'some_func'])->name('some_route_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked.

```
<button class="btn border button" id="go-back-btn" onclick="window.location='{!! route('getDashboardScreen') !!}?MilkCompanyID={!!session('MilkCompanyID')!!}'">Go back</button>
```